# Do you need spacers for subway tiles?

Tags: bathtub, ceramic-tile

A lot of Youtube videos is showing subway tiles being installed without spacers...
Do you really need spacers or not for Subway tiles (Bathtub surround tiling) ??

Thank you

Andrew

Answer (score 6, accepted):

4-1/4" and some larger wall tiles have bumps cast in that act as spacers. Unless you want a larger gap, no additional spacers are needed.

Whether your particular tile has them is uncertain. They're often necessary to prevent sagging with heavier tile while the mortar or mastic sets.

Comment: +1 To rephrase, if the tile being used doesn't have bumps cast into them, or you want a larger grout space than what the bumps provide, you'll need to use spacers.